# How can I use google or-tools in ruby for my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, traveling-salesman, or-tools

I need to solve tsp problem in my rails application.
I want to use google or-tools for solving this problem of tsp.
The documentation[1](https://developers.google.com/optimization/) tells about using or-tools in c++, c#, java and python.
The code for solving tsp using or-tools in python is working fine.
But I need to use or-tools in ruby for my rails app.
How can I do this?

Comment: Are you sure they work with `ruby`? I don't see a mention of it on their page (_"Google created OR-Tools in C++, but you can also use it with Python, C#, or Java."_) - https://developers.google.com/optimization/introduction/installing/source

Comment: If they are not available for ruby, What other ways might be there for using or-tools in the rails app. Can I call python file in my ruby library? Are there any unofficial version available on GitHub of or-tools library's ruby version  @JagdeepSingh

Comment: I am afraid i don't know more here. You will have to research. :)

Comment: Why are you afraid @JagdeepSingh, Is it because of my DP :-p

Answer (score 0):

or-tools uses SWIG to wrap it for those other languages.  You could probably reuse the code for Ruby.  A few classes are probably easy, the whole API probably non-trivial.

Otherwise you could go through one of the supported languages -With jruby for example.